# Forming a 16-bit signed two's complement for different decimal values

Tags: binary, bit-manipulation, twos-complement

I've been trying to convert different values, mostly decimals, into 2's complement format. I seem to have trouble with them, especially fractions.

Lets say I have an integer value of L = 2^16 - 46, and i want to convert it to 2's complement.

L = 65490, which seems to give me 1111111111010010 in binary. 
I then converted it to 2's complement by swapping the bits and adding one, thus giving me L(2's) = 0000000000101110.

Now lets assume I have a decimal with fractions, for example K = 0.2522429. Converting that into binary, we get 0.01000000_10010011. Again converting by the 2's complement, I end up with 0.10111111_01101101, which seems correct.

But what should i do if the decimal does not match up as 16-bits? Or if I want 2's complement for the operation K/16?

I would get K = 0.01576518125, which would result in 0.00000100_00001001_0011 in binary. As we can see, we now have 20 bits instead of 6, and the 2's complement would be 0.1111_10111111_01101101. How would I be able to get the result as 16-bit for the operation K/16, and for example different variations such as -K/8, K/4, -K/2?

Answer (score 0):

> Lets say I have an integer value of L = 2^16 - 46, and i want to convert it to 2's complement.

If you want to code a number N in 2's complement, you must ensure -2^15≤N≤2^15-1, and you cannot code the number 2^16-46 as a positive number in 2's complement on 16 bits. More precisely, 2^16-46 will be the (positive) number whose binary code will be used to represent in 2's C on 16 bits the negative number -46.

> Now lets assume I have a decimal with fractions, for example K = 0.2522429. Converting that into binary, we get 0.01000000_10010011. Again converting by the 2's complement, I end up with 0.10111111_01101101, which seems correct.

Not really. The 2's C of N=0.01000000_10010011 is N'=1.10111111_01101101 (or on 16 bits N=0.01000000_1001001  and N'=1.10111111_0110110). Historically, fractional numbers where the first application of 2's C and 2's C of N is the number N' such as N+N'=2. In other word N' is the number that must be added to N to get 2, hence the name of two's complement.

> But what should i do if the decimal does not match up as 16-bits?

I do not really understand your question. K=0.2522429 already cannot be coded exactly on 16 bits and 0.01000000_10010011<sub>b</sub>=0.252243042 and, as it is frequent with fractional numbers, you can only have a binary approximation of these numbers. Decimal fractional numbers are expressed as sums of negative powers of 10 and most of the time their value cannot be expressed exactly as sums of negative powers of 2 (as 1/3 cannot be expressed precisely as a finite sum of negative powers of 10).

So if you want to code a fractional number on 16 bits, you find a binary approximation of the number and you only keep 16 bits.

> Or if I want 2's complement for the operation K/16?

Dividing by 16 is right shifting by 4. For 2s C numbers, the shift must be arithmetic and the MSB (sign bit) must be duplicated. This will ensure that this is equivalent to a  division by 4. Hence if N'=1.10111111_01101101, N'/4=1.1111_10111111_01101101. Of course the number of bits is >16, and you must only keep the 16 most significant bits N'=1.11111011_1111011 which is equal to −0,015777588 which is an approximation of the result.

But is due to division and is identical for any number in any base and any coding system with a finite number of digits. For instance 53=00110101  and coded as an integer 53/16=00000011 or 0.12325621/100=0.00123156 if you keep only 8 digits at the right of the point.